# Testing Framework Documentation

Tags: linux

I need some documentation or reference for testmgr which is the testing framework for cryptographic operations in linux. In testmgr some structures have been defined. Can I get a document which describes all that has been used and its usage and requirement.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/crypto/testmgr.c This gives you all the structures defined and http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/crypto/ this shows various other files information.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker